# (Google) Enhanced conversions aren't processed because your user email data field is incorrectly formatted

Tags: javascript, php, gtag.js

We're tracking conversions manually based on conditional logic upon loading a page. A PHP script returns HTML containing the gtag script to the page the user is on.

Here is the code that we know is being sent:

```
return <<<HTML
    <script>
        try {
            gtag('config', $GOOGLE_AD_CONVERSION_ID);
            gtag('set', 'user_data', {
                "email": $email_string,
                "phone_number": $phone
            });
            function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
                var callback = function () {
                    console.log('gtag conversion tracked');
                    // We don't use this
                    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
                        window.location = url;
                    }
                };
                gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                    'send_to': $GOOGLE_AD_CLICK_SEND_TO,
                    'value': $amount,
                    'currency': $currency_string,
                    'transaction_id': $transaction_id,
                    'event_callback': callback
                });
                return false;
            }
            gtag_report_conversion(undefined);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error during gtag conversion", e);
        }
    </script>
    HTML;
```

All variables except $amount and $phone are wrapped in quotation marks so that they are valid strings in JavaScript.

I realized after I got this error that $phone also needs to be wrapped. Would that be the reason that it doesn't recognize the email as properly formatted? The server is logging the HTML it sends, so I took a look at it, and the email field looks perfectly normal to me. Example with identifying information removed: `"foo.bar@telenet.be".`

The other possibility it gives is that the email isn't hashed, but it says on [this page](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/13258081?sjid=11449411360579569879-EU&visit_id=638469773758396191-4115529565&rd=2#Add_a_code_snippet&zippy=%2Cconfigure-your-conversion-page-google-tag%2Cfind-enhanced-conversions-fields-on-your-conversion-page):

> The feature uses a secure one-way hashing algorithm called [SHA256](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9004655) on your first-party customer data, such as email addresses, before sending to Google

So that implies that it shouldn't be pre-hashed.

I would wait to ask this question until after trying out having $phone be wrapped in quotation marks, but my company is very eager to get it working. If that resolves the issue, I'll report back about it.

Summary: is there something wrong with the way this is implemented? If so, what's wrong with it? Or does leaving the $phone variable without quotation marks in the JavaScript ruin the email part too?

Comment: Depends on what your phone numbers look like. If they only contain digits, and perhaps `+` or `-`, they are probably still a valid expression in JS (even if the resulting value might make not much sense.) If they contained anything that invalidated the JS syntax - then you should rather not see any tracking data being sent to begin with, because a syntax error would prevent it all from executing to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error went away after the phone number was wrapped in quotes.